# Proxmox при перезагрузке ВМ выдает 1 и тот-же ip адрес

Tags: сеть, ansible, dhcp, proxmox

господа знатоки.
Суть в следующем:
Имеется proxmox VE. На нем хочется через ansible поднимать ВМ-ки (ubuntu 20.04) в большом колличестве, имеется плейбук:

```
---
- name: up stage VM
  hosts: localhost
  ignore_errors: yes
  tasks:
    - name: Clone VMs
      proxmox_kvm:
        node: "{{ node }}"
        name: "{{ name }}"
        api_user: "{{ api_user }}"
        api_password: "{{ api_password }}"
        api_host: "{{ api_host }}"
        clone: "{{ clone_vm }}"

    - name: Pause for 1 minutes to build clone
      pause:
        minutes: 1

    - name: get vmid
      shell: "qm list | grep {{ name }} | cut -b 8,9,10"
      register: qm

    - debug: msg="{{ qm.stdout }}"
    - name: Start VMs
      proxmox_kvm:
        api_host:     "{{ api_host }}"
        api_password: "{{ api_password }}"
        api_user:     "{{ api_user }}"
        vmid:         "{{ qm.stdout }}"
        node:         "{{ node }}"
        state:        started
        name:         "{{ name }}"

    - name: wait for up VM
      pause:
        minutes: 1

    - name: get new dhcp ip
      shell: qm guest exec {{ qm.stdout }} -- bash -c "dhclient -r && dhclient"

    - name: Get IP VM
      shell: qm guest cmd {{ qm.stdout }} network-get-interfaces | grep ip-address | grep 192 | cut -d ':' -f 2 | cut -d '"' -f 2
      register: vmip

    - debug: msg="{{ vmip.stdout }}"
```

Плейбук работает более чем хорошо, но если посмотреть в него внимательно, то можно увидеть неплохой такой костыль:

```
- name: get new dhcp ip
  shell: qm guest exec {{ qm.stdout }} -- bash -c "dhclient -r && dhclient"
```

Сделано это для того, что-бы при разворачивании менялся IP у машины, потому-что по дефолту он получает 101(условно, иногда и другие) IP и все. Костыль работает и очень хорошо, но если машину рестартнуть, то он обратно получит 101 IP, отсюда вопрос, почему? Как это пофиксить? Где может быть проблема?

Опережая пару встречных вопросов:
ВМ разворачивается из шаблона, созданного заранее, в шаблоне при создании указывался dhcp, и да, MAC у ВМ-ок у всех разный.

Comment: Ну а логи dhcp сервака чё говорят?

Comment: @donRumata да вот ничего, просто говорят в духе:192.168.1.101  XXX.name.local запросил Ip
новый IP 192.168.1.101

Comment: И чё и мак даже не видится?

Comment: @donRumata нет, мак не показывается, но я заходил на сами виртуалки и смотрел маки там, и в proxmox-е, везде разные у всех уникальный мак

Comment: Какой сервер используешь?

Comment: @donRumata если ты иммеешь ввиду железный, то сборка кастомная (Для отладки), по сути i7 64 оперативы, вот и все...

Comment: Не, я про софт, который раздаёт айпишники.

Comment: @donRumata WindowsServer 2008 r2

Comment: Нуууу... несмотря, что у нас на работе есть лицухи на винду и аж 2 домена, мы всё равно юзаем `isc dhcp server`. Попробуй поднять его просто в качестве эксперемента и посмотреть поедет или нет.